# Joomla creates folders inside cache with 640 permission

Tags: joomla-2.5, cache, file-permissions

I have Joomla! 2.5.18 and when I clean cache are either folders inside /cache newly created or overwritten with permission from 755 to 640.

Why is that happening?

I've checked through the files and there is nowhere set that newly created files should be created with permission 640. 
For all the components to work properly I need this kind of permissions.

Even the user (and group) is the same as for every folder.

Where is exactly is this defined? At some file?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please first update to Joomla 2.5.28 as you're 10 minor versions behind. Then check to see if the issue still occurs

Comment: As @Lodder said - update Joomla first. As for the question itself, can you clarify what is the issue you have? Is anything you can't do because of the permissions? are you getting any error? can't clean the cache? And what do you mean with the "this kind of permissions" and "user and group is the same as for every folder"?

Comment: Is there any setting where I can set with what permission have the folders and files created inside cache? Maybe someone set it for security reasons, but I don't have any information about that. As I checked, all other Joomla installations that we have, all files and folders inside cache have permission 755. Thank you.

Comment: Are you in godaddy hosting?